# "Run as administrator" and getting "My Documents" folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, acl, impersonation, administrator

I'm shipping a visual studio template with an installer that requires admin rights but the problem is: if the user is NOT administrator and installs my program with "Run As.. administrator", I canNOT get "My Documents" folder for him (it is automatically set to the administrator's one like

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents
```

How can I either

- Install the .zip in the Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates directory for every user
- Install the .zip for the user who started the installer

?

Comment: If it's running as admin, why not drop the templates in program files?

Comment: The .zip for my template is not working in the normal VS2012 Program Files template directory. If you can find a working directory where to drop such a template let me know and I'll mark your answer as accepted

Comment: "Not working" as in it doesn't show up?  Restarted VS?

Comment: Nope, I have a project template and it needs to be in "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\My Exported Templates\" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd885241.aspx)

Comment: Wait, that doesn't make sense.  That's where project templates are created when you are designing them.  You want to install the resulting template on new machines, right?

Comment: yes correct. But the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\VC" dir is not working if I put my zip in there. Is there another one?

Comment: You might be missing the locale subdirectory.  For me, it would be "..templates\vc\1033".  You can find the codes for locales [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).  Not sure if that's the missing piece.

Comment: Thank you Will, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem :(